# Getting error "The security token included in the request is invalid" when using AWS ruby sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm getting this error **"The security token included in the request is invalid"** when trying to get hosted zones list from Route53 using AWS Ruby SDK, eventhough I'm running my script from instance having "full privileges" IAM role. 
Here is the full trace :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.6.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:318:in `return_or_raise': The security token included in the request is invalid (AWS::Route53::Errors::InvalidClientTokenId)
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.6.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:419:in `client_request'
  from (eval):3:in `list_hosted_zones'
  from test.rb:7
```

And the test.rb file :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config()

r53 = AWS::Route53.new
resp = r53.client.list_hosted_zones
resp[:hosted_zones].each do |zone|
  puts zone
end
```

It seems that the issue is related to Route53 sdk methods, because I've tested with another code to manage EC2 and Elastic Load Balancers with same SDK and it's working just fine.

What do you think ? Did I missed something ? Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the signature version 3 https signer that omitted the session token from the request.  A new release was published today (1.7.1) that addressed this issue.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much Trevor ! Really appreciate to see how fast the issue was fixed :)

Comment: @trevor-rowe This seems to have happened to me today.  Were you involved in the previous fix?

Comment: @esmit Yes I was, though I have not heard of any other reports of a regression.

Comment: @TrevorRowe It turns out that it was my mistake.  Thanks for the reply.